# Version of Stone Weierstrass for functions not vanishing at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

I am trying to see what is known about uniform density of function spaces in $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or $C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$). By uniform density, I mean density with respect to uniform convergence on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, not any compactly supported version of uniform convergence. I do not know of any version of Stone Weierstrass theorem covering such cases. But I would be happy to see certain special examples where people have proved density of certain function spaces in $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or $C_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I am just curious about this, I do not have an especially good reason for asking this. As a possible example, if someone has proved somewhere that continuous functions of bounded smooth functions are dense in $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$, I would be interested in learning how such a proof might work. Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Please remark that the sup-norm is not a norm unless you add some condition that makes it always finite.

Comment: @Siminore Edited.

Comment: The Stone-Weierstrass Theorem deals with polynomials, and it is intuitive that polynomials have a rather rigid behavior at infinity. Moreover, continuous function on the real line (take $n=1$ for simplicity) need not be integrable. In other words your question is interesting, although dense subspaces must be rather wildly-behaved: they should approximate unbounded, nowhere differentiable, non integrable functions...

Comment: @Siminore Weierstrass deals with polynomials. Stone-Weierstrass is much more general, dealing with an algebra of continuous function on a compact set subject to a few conditions.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that the space $C_b (\Bbb{R}^n)$ (bounded continuous functions with the sup norm) is **not seperable**.

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/214543/21564).

Answer (score 0):

Even though the sup-norm is not a finitely-valued function on $C(R^n)$ we can can still talk of uniform convergence, and density. However even with $n=1$, if $\{f_k : k \in N \}$ is a subset of $C(R)$, there exists $g \in C(R)$ with $g(k)=1+f_k(k)$ for each $k \in N$.